# Drag end of track in Audacity

Tags: audacity

How do I drag the end of a track, making it shorter or longer?
When the cursor looks like in this screenshot, I will only move a track (time shift).

[image: hovering end of track]

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Audacity is a quite simple program. If you want to shorten a clip, you need to cut it. If you want to make it longer... perhaps you should generate a silence clip at the end?

Comment: I want to drag the end resulting either in a shortened or a prolonged track with silence in the prolongation

Answer (score 2):

1. To shorten the clip choose selection tool (<kbd>F1</kbd>), select portion of the clip you want to remove and press <kbd>Del</kbd> key.
2. To add silence at the end, move cursor to the end of the clip (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>), select menu Generate > Silence and choose length. If you want, you can then merge the two clips, by selecting the whole track and then: Edit > Clip Boundaries > Join